# asp.net mvc show list vies based in logged user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

You will be appreciated to share your experience how to show the data list view being filtered according to the logged user.
 Regards
Arun Sahani, Kathmandu

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what credentials you use to filter the data. Nevertheless, you need to add a field in the model that you want o retrieve the list of.For example:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [Required]        
    [Display(Name = "Product ID")]
    public int productID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string productName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Product Price(RM)")]
    public double productPrice { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string productAddedBy{ get; set; }
}
```

Notice the 'productAddedBy' column in Product table as you need to assign the value of logged user of either id or name when you create a product:

**BY ID**

```
//Initialise product instance
Product p = new Product();
p.productAddedBy= User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

**BY Name**

```
//Initialise product instance
Product p = new Product();
p.productAddedBy= User.Identity.GetUserName();
```

After saving the product into database, you can do a LINQ query to filter the data from DbSet and pass the result to a view. Of course, you will need to initialise an instance of your db context class and the user must be logged in.

```
List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
productList = 'your_db_context_instance'.Product.Where(x=> x.productAddedBy == User.Identity.GetUserId());
return View(productList);
```

The above codes will get all the products added by user based on the id of logged user. The final thing is to pass the 'productList' to a strongly typed view and you're good to go.